# "str.length - 1" devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando averiguar por qué el siguiente código no está funcionando como creo que debería. Es una función que invierte el orden de un string, pero haga lo que haga, siempre la primera letra aparece como `undefined`.

```js
function wordReverse(str){
  let newStrig;

  for (let i = str.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
      newStrig += str[i];
  }

  console.log(newStrig);
}

wordReverse('palabra');
```

Comment: let newStrig=''; , tienes que inicializar la cadena donde almacenaras la palabra

Comment: Funcionó gracias. ¿Pero entonces por qué solo ocurre con la primera letra?

Comment: Cuando realizas operaciones de cadena con valores de otro tipo, Javascript tratará de convertirlos a cadena, resultando en: 'undefined', 'null', '[Object Object]', etc., dependiendo del caso. Si defines una variable, sin especificar valor, por defecto será `undefined`, aunque exista y puedas acceder a ella (cosas raras del lenguaje); es por eso que debes inicializar con un valor adecuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se presenta porque estás sumando/concatenando a la variable `newString` sin definirle algún valor al declararla. Podrías colocar `let  newString = ''` para que a la primera iteración no se presente el `undefined` cuando sumas la primera letra.

```js
function wordReverse(str){
  let newStrig = '';

  for (let i = str.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
      newStrig += str[i];
  }

  console.log(newStrig);
}

wordReverse('palabra');
```